# Membership IS or membership AT

Tags: conjunctions

I wish to say that I sell membership cheaply (in my opinion). Let's say for $99 for one year. What's the right way to say it on my site:
1.) Membership at only $99  OR
2.) Membership is only $99?
One more thing... In this context "only" and "just" mean the same (interchangeable)? like "membership is just $99" or "membership at just $99".

Comment: What about, "The membership fee is only/just $99 per year." OR "The annual membership fee is only/just $99."

Comment: A word "fee" is kinda out of place in an advertisement. Sounds too official and boring.

Comment: Talk about boredom. Even the sample sentence you provided has a tint of boredom (well, at least not the same level of boredom when considering the 'official' wording).What about, "Become a member for a year for only 99 dollars!", "For only $99, enjoy the benefits/privileges of a member!" I suggest you add an exclamation point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*At* makes "only $99" something like a "place" or "point."

Meaning that you are subtly implying you have moved the price temporarily to $99, but it may not be $99 in the future.  Or for some other reason the price may change and you are saying where the price is now.

You may want this subtle implication of price increase (though it can mean decrease as well) in an advertisement to goad the viewer/reader into a sense of urgency.

If the normal price of the membership is $99, then *is* is typically more appropriate.

Comment: I agree. Using 'at' does add that sense of "temporary" change in pricing (something promotional?), if I correctly remember the last TV shopping channel I've seen, they either use "for only" or "at only". (I'm biased towards the former though). :)

Comment: It's pretty rare in business that a price don't change. Inflation, supply and demand etc. For my ear "at" sounds more "alive". Though I'm not a native English speaker. From marketing perspective, a sense of urgency is always nice.

Answer (score 1):

As an English speaker, it seems that the second option would be the better choice, however both could be used. If you used "is", then you should say how long the membership is for:
**membership is only $99 per year!**